# Hybrid PC/Tablet website

Tags: javascript, html, css

What is the reliable approach to develop a website that is used on the computer that is a hybrid, in other words have both a mouse (or a touch pad) and a touch screen and can be used by a user in both ways at the same time.

Especially the question is how to deal with the mouse cursor, that must be seen when using a mouse and is distracting once the user uses her finger.

The goal is to develop a single page, not two separate pages, one for mouse and other for the touch. Style `cursor = 'none'` is killing the cursor over the specified elements completely, this is not desired.

I am not talking about scrolling or zooming, but about clickable/touchable divs/spans/images, that can react some how. For instance I have a table where each cell could be clicked to mark (change color). Same with buttons, once you touch the button with the finger, the mouse cursor will stay on top of it and distract.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTML5 does support the concept of [touch events](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/mobile/touch/), perhaps you can dynamically change behavior/style etc   in javascript based on detected events (e.g. turn your page into touch mode "cursor = none" if you detect a touch event but switch back to mouse visible style if you detect mouse move events).

This is by no means completely reliable as touchevent implementation is browser (somewhat patchy support at that), OS and possibly hardware dependent. e.g. Older OSes might translate touch event into mouse click events or older browsers might not support OS's touch events and OS fallsback to mouse click events.

See [Touch And Mouse](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/mobile/touchandmouse/) for more info that might help you.